# Find rows that have changed in the latest dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes as follows:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[2,3,4]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,4],'B':[2,2,5]})
```

Following code gives me just a difference between 2 dataframes, how to get only changes from the df2?

```
changed_rows = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Left merge on all columns and use merge indicator to identify the modified rows

```
df2.merge(df1, how='left', indicator=True).query("_merge != 'both'")
```

---

```
   A  B     _merge
1  2  2  left_only
2  4  5  left_only
```

Answer (score 1):

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html#pandas.DataFrame.compare

I think something like this is what you're after. Self is df1, df2 is 'other' `df1.compare(df2)`.

```
d = df1.compare(df2, align_axis=0, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=False)

print(d)
           A    B
0 self   NaN  NaN
  other  NaN  NaN
1 self   NaN  3.0
  other  NaN  2.0
2 self   3.0  4.0
  other  4.0  5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df2[~df1.eq(df2).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   A  B
1  2  2
2  4  5
```